# Windows IIS with Windows authentication and access for single host

Tags: windows, authentication, iis

I have set following IIS application on host **HOST1**:

- site bindings: type: http, port: 8080, IP address: *
- alias: APP1
- physical path: C:\inetpub\app1
- port: 8080
- anonymous and basic auth disabled
- windows auth enabled

Now if I try to access this application from host **HOST2**, I get windows authentication form, as expected.

Is it possible to set authentication for application APP1 so, that no windows authentication is used when APP1 is accessed from host **HOST2**?

Comment: Do you want to remove windows authentication ?

Comment: Disable windows authentication if its not required and it wont ask you windows credentials. Simple.